# Debian/Ubuntu - Prevent services from being started and enabled upon install

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I like to set up Debian or Ubuntu as servers and have to install many applications before configuring them. Sometimes, I install an application just so that I have the option to use it at a later date if needed.

I don't want these apps to automatically be enabled and started. This creates problems, especially if their settings hasn't been changed and there are conflicts with other apps.

For example, I installed the following software: `apt install nginx apache2 lighttpd`.

And when I reboot, Nginx is listening on port 80, mis-configured and insecure, and I have to disable it.

[image]

I disable it and reboot, see now who took over the port:

[image]

If I disable `lighttpd`, Apache2 will take its place.

This doesn't make sense, I feel like I'm fighting with the applications I install... Any way to make it stop? Any way to disable this behavior of enabling and starting services upon installation?

EDIT

Found a solution for preventing auto start:

```
echo exit 101 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

Found a solution for preventing auto enable:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723679/547917

But this is ridiculous there's nothing simpler, some kind of swtch using `apt --no-enable --no-start`, for example.

Comment: Hard to believe there is no way to prevent services from being started upon installation, incredible!

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that newly-installed services — at least, those configured using systemd units, which is most now — are disabled by default by setting up a systemd preset:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system-preset
echo 'disable *' | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system-preset/99-default-disable.preset
```

See [`man systemd.preset`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) for details.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, when I installed dnsmasq afterwards, it tried to start it and there was a big red message because port 53 is already taken by another service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your own package and do not want the service to automatically start, you can install a preset file. There are many locations, I chose the following for my package because the folder already exists with the default systemd file:

```
/etc/systemd/system-preset/
```

I named my file after my package with `50-` at the start and `.preset` as the extension:

```
50-<package-name>.preset
```

And inside the file, I added one line:

```
disable <service-name>.service
```

Usually, `<service-name>` is the same as `<package-name>`, but not always.

Now, in the `debian/<package-name>.install` file, I have one more line:

```
/usr/share/<package-name>/50-<package-name>.preset /etc/systemd/system-preset/
```

Somewhere in one of my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I install that `.preset` file in the `/usr/share/<package-name>/` directory because you cannot directly install files under `/etc/...`. Something like this:

```
project(service-config)

INSTALL(
    FILES
        50-<package-name>.preset

    DESTINATION
        share/<package-name>
)
```

Now the service status says:

```
...; vendor preset: disabled)
```

In other words, start with a disabled service. In my case, the service requires the installation of a key before it has a chance to work so I wanted it disabled by default.